# stata shp2dta does not work --> 15: point, polyine, or polygon shapefile required

Tags: stata, spatial, shapefile

I try to convert a `shapefile` into `dta`. format using `shp2dta` ado. I've done it many times before exactly in the same way but this time I only get the error

> 15: point, polyine, or polygon shapefile required

I can open the shapefile in ArcGIS as well as in QGIS, so the shapefile seems to be alright.

The shape contains information about 85 000 polygons including 2 attributes (as dbf)

my code: `shp2dta using ..., database(datab) coordinates(datacoord) genid(id) gencentroids(c) replace`

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: The latest version of `shp2dta` (from SSC; explaining the provenance of user-written commands is always helpful) is `*! version 1.0.9 15jul2015` so check yours by `which shp2dta`. The text of that error message does not occur in the source code. Otherwise the answer presumably lies in your file. If you don't get better answers, I would contact the first author directly.

Comment: The latest version seems to mention support for PolygonZ shapefiles "Added support for all shapefile formats" so I think my hunch answer is right...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the "15" in the error message is a reference to the shape type, in this case "PolygonZ" - ie polygons with a Z (elevation) value.

(Table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile#Shapefile_shape_format_.28.shp.29 )

Well-behaved software should handle this gracefully - either deal with it or drop it and create a 2d data set. `shp2dta` seems to just complain and die.

Try loading it into QGIS/Arc and saving it back out, there may be an option to create a 2D version or it might happen by default.

My hunch can be confirmed if you can run `ogrinfo -so -al` on the shapefile, or check the metadata in QGIS.

It does look like the latest version has support for PolygonZ though - try that.